# Дублируются хлебные крошки в Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Не могу понять, везде тыкал код,

```
<?php
if ( function_exists('yoast_breadcrumb') ) {
  yoast_breadcrumb( '<p id="breadcrumbs">','</p>' );
}
?>
```

Но все равно дублируются хлебные крошки на каждом посту. Не могу найти файл нужный, где наверное стоит разместить данный код так, чтобы он был не к каждому посту привязан, а просто под h1 был или над h1. Тема в вордпрессе Basic!

Comment: В настройках темы нет переключения вкл/выкл хлебных крошек? Обычно бывает и потребность самому размещать код вывода отпадает

Comment: К сожалению нету.

Comment: Вообще такое стоило только в header.php разместить. Перечислите, пожалуйста, в каких файлах Вы подключили данный код. Можете ещё приложить скрин дублированного breadcrumb.